# showexpl: latex gives an error (undefined control sequence) when using showexpl (LTXexample environment) in files with external .sty files

Tags: listings, undefined, showexpl

I am quite new to LaTeX and recently started learning tikz. I use 'showexpl' and 'listings' package to generate examples of tikz codes and their outputs in overleaf. Almost all of my files preamble are too large. So, I create several packages (.sty files) with each containing small parts of my preamble and then I put all of them of in the main file inside a single usepackage. But, when doing this with with showexpl I get an error 'undefined control sequence'.Although the file(main.tex) compiles fine without any issue but still it produces error. How can I get get rid of the errors?
Here is the link of my source code:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/nwkdqyrmdcvf
https://www.overleaf.com/8629643923mmtjtdbfmrfs

EDIT-1: As stated in comment, I have tried my best to post here the MWE, although it is quite large and messy since I have to gather several pieces of code from several files and put them together,so it became scattered

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%==================================={geometry}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={18cm,25cm},left=2cm}
%==================================={other}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings,keyval}
\lstloadlanguages{[AspectJ]java,[AlLaTeX]TeX,[ANSI]C,}
\lstloadaspects{keywordcomments,procnames,hyper,formats}
%==================================={lstnewenvironment}
\lstnewenvironment{code}[1][]
{\lstset{style=mystyle,language={[PTX2]ProTeX}}}{}
\lstMakeShortInline[style=mystyle,language={[PTX]ProTeX}]!
%==================================={lstdefinelanguage}
\lstdefinelanguage[PTX]{ProTeX}
{language=[AlLaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
moredelim=**[l][\color{blue}]{\\},
moredelim=**[s][\color{SpringGreen3}]{[}{]},
moredelim=**[s][\color{SpringGreen3}]{[<}{>]},
moredelim=**[s][\color{red}]{\{}{\}},
moredelim=**[s][\color{red}]{\{<}{>\}},
moredelim=**[s][\color{Turquoise2}]{<}{>}}
%==================================={lstdefinelanguage-2}
\lstdefinelanguage[PTX2]{ProTeX}
{language=[AlLaTeX]TeX,
basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
morekeywords={lstloadlanguages,lstloadaspects,lstset,lstalias,lstdefinelanguage,lstdefinestyle,lstdefineformat,lstnewenvironment,
lstMakeShortInline},
keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
moretexcs={color,lstlistoflistings,thelstlisting},
texcsstyle=*\color{blue}\bfseries,
commentstyle=\color{SpringGreen4}\itshape,
}
%==================================={lstdefinestyle}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
%...................................(Line numbers)
{numbers=left,
numberfirstline=true,
numberstyle=\bfseries\scriptsize\color{black},
numbersep=10pt,
firstnumber=auto,
%...................................(frame-shape)
frame=single,
frame=TBRL,
framesep=0pt,
rulesep=2pt,
framerule=0pt,
xleftmargin=1cm,
framexleftmargin=1cm,
framextopmargin=10pt,
framexbottommargin=10pt,
%...................................(frame-color)
backgroundcolor=\color{black!2},
rulecolor=\color{white},
fillcolor=\color{black!2},
rulesepcolor=\color{blue},
escapeinside={?}{?},
%...................................(others)
breaklines=true,
breakindent=0pt}
%==================================={lstdefinestyle-2}
\lstdefinestyle{explstyle}
%...................................(Line numbers)
{numbers=left,
numberfirstline=true,
numberstyle=\bfseries\scriptsize\color{black},
numbersep=10pt,
firstnumber=auto,
%...................................(frame-shape)
frame=single,
frame=TBRL,
framesep=0pt,
rulesep=2pt,
framerule=0pt,
xleftmargin=1cm,
framexleftmargin=1cm,
framextopmargin=10pt,
framexbottommargin=10pt,
%...................................(frame-color)
backgroundcolor=\color{SpringGreen4!5},
rulecolor=\color{SpringGreen4!5},
fillcolor=\color{SpringGreen4!5},
rulesepcolor=\color{SpringGreen4!5},
escapeinside={?}{?},
%...................................(others)
breaklines=true,
breakindent=0pt}
\newtcolorbox{box2}
{colback=SpringGreen4!5,colframe=SpringGreen4,fonttitle=\bfseries}
\newtcbox{\minibox}[2][]
{colback=red!5,colframe=red,fonttitle=\bfseries,title={#2}#1}
\lstset{explpreset={style=mystyle,language={[PTX2]ProTeX}}}
\renewcommand\ResultBox{\fcolorbox{green}{Snow1}}
\setlength\ResultBoxSep{10pt}
\setlength\ResultBoxRule{2pt}
\begin{document}
\lstset{explpreset={style=explstyle,language={[PTX2]ProTeX}}}
\begin{box2}
\begin{LTXexample}[pos=r,justification=\centering]
\begin{document}
!Hello World!
\end{document}
\end{LTXexample}
\end{box2}
\end{document}
```

Note:In the code I have used `\lstMakeShortInline[style=mystyle,language={[PTX]ProTeX}]!`to make ! sign as delimiters for inline code snippets.
Note: When compiled in overleaf(or TeXlive) it produces an error as undefined control sequence.
Note: If the lines from `\begin{box2}` to `\end{box2}` (located at the end) is replaced by any random text the error goes away. So, the problem might be in that lines but I still cannot figure out

Comment: please make a small complete example and add it as a code block to the question, do not use external links as the question is archived here forever and willnot be understandable if that oveleaf project changes

Comment: probably unrelated but why define these with arguments? `\newcommand{\n}[1]{\newline}\newcommand{\p}[1]{\par}`

Comment: @David Carlisle thanks for pointing out. I have not noticed that there were arguments as wrote them in hurry although it has no impact on overall compilation process. I will rectify them later.

Comment: well if you make a newline with `abc \n xyz` then the current definition will silently discard the `x`.  (I am surprised you need shortcut macros for `\newline` or `\par` since neither should appear in documents except in very unusual circumstances.